# I used CrossMediaManager is take a time for playing audio from URL

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

CrossMediaManager takes time for playing audio from URL.
It takes 10-20 seconds to play audio. Any other Plugin or code for play, pause and resume Audio

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(Mp3Url);
```

Comment: You said that CrossMediaManager takes 10-20 seconds to play audio? What it means? You means that it takes 10-20 seconds to start play audio when you click play button? I do one sample about CrossMediaManager, but don't have this issue,if you don't want to use CrossMediaManager to play audio, you can implement this Audio Player in Xamarin.Forms with the help of DependencyService to do this:https://github.com/juniandotnet/xamarin-audio-player

Comment: And if you access this MP3 url by other means on the device, it plays immediately?